# codeigniter transactions - trans_start trans_complete trans_status

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, transactions, status

Just trying to figure out why counterfeiters transactions are not behaving the way I expected them to.

---

This transactions **trans_status()** triggers '**TRANS SUCCESS**' :

```
    $this->db->trans_start();
      $this->db->query("UPDATE `TABLE1` SET `NAME` = 'AAA' WHERE `ID` = '1'");
      $this->db->query("UPDATE `TABLE2` SET `NAME` = 'BBB' WHERE `ID` = '2'");
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){// Check if transaction result successful
       echo "<BR>------- TRANS FAILED -------</BR>";
    }else{
       echo "<BR>------- TRANS SUCCESS -------</BR>";
    }
```

**TABLE1** gets updated with '**AAA**' and **TABLE2** gets updated with '**BBB**'

---

This transactions **trans_status()** reports '**TRANS FAILED**' as expected, because '**incorrectID**' column does **NOT** exist in the **TABLE2**:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
  $this->db->query("UPDATE `TABLE1` SET `NAME` = 'AAA' WHERE `ID` = '1'");
  $this->db->query("UPDATE `TABLE2` SET `NAME` = 'BBB' WHERE `incorrectID` = '2'");
$this->db->trans_complete();

if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){// Check if transaction result successful
   echo "<BR>------- TRANS FAILED -------</BR>";
}else{
   echo "<BR>------- TRANS SUCCESS -------</BR>";
}
```

**TABLE1** IS ***NOT*** updated with '**AAA**' and **TABLE2** IS ***NOT*** updated with '**BBB**'

---

Yet, THIS transactions **trans_status()** reports '**TRANS SUCCESS**' even though there is no **ID** with the value '**55**' **TABLE2** ?!?!:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
  $this->db->query("UPDATE `TABLE1` SET `NAME` = 'AAA' WHERE `ID` = '1'");
  $this->db->query("UPDATE `TABLE2` SET `NAME` = 'BBB' WHERE `ID` = '55'");
$this->db->trans_complete();

if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){// Check if transaction result successful
   echo "<BR>------- TRANS FAILED -------</BR>";
}else{
   echo "<BR>------- TRANS SUCCESS -------</BR>";
}
```

**TABLE1** ***DOES*** updated with '**AAA**' and **TABLE2** ***DOES NOT*** get updated, as there is NO **ID** of **55** on **TABLE2** - yet I expect it to roll back because the TABLE2 UPDATE will not be successful.

What gives? I thought the idea behind the transaction is that everything between the **trans_start()** and **trans_complete()** must be successful for the whole transaction to be successful.. Otherwise the whole **transaction is rolled back**.

I have tried this with SET and UPDATE and have the same problem.
The first **db->query()** will commit and save the changes, leaving the second **db->query()** unfulfilled and the **trans_status()** reporting it as a success???

What am I missing here?

Thanks all :)

Regards.

Comment: I think the problem may be that codeigniters transactions `$_trans_status` only gets set to false when the query fails. A query that returns no results isn't a fail in codeigniters eyes.

Comment: Hmmm... OK - So then it is not concerned if a transaction is completed successfully - but that a transaction is not malformed?

Comment: I'm still confused - what if my call was to create a record - I only want to continue the transaction if record A is created... if it does not care if the actual success of the call.... what's the point... still confused - but thanks for your reply : )

Answer (score 2):

What transactions are looking for successful queries. Your query

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID = 55");
```

is a proper query and it runs accordingly and return 0 rows. Not returning any rows does not mean that the query failed to run.

If you provide your example for the update queries, it might shed more light on the matter.

Comment: Good point @dakdad - thanks for pointing that out. I did not think of that fact with the simple query. I revised the question to show the true update attempts. The example where only one table updates gives a successful transaction report - yet I am expecting the transaction to fail if not all queries are successful.

Comment: I think that the codeigniter is working correct - my understanding of transactions is wrong. I think @dakdad and Jeemusu answers are both correct - it is not an error to NOT succeed in updating a non existent row - so the full transaction is seen as successful. I tested this with MySQL BEGIN and COMMIT transaction method alone - and the same thing happened - the transaction did not fail because there was NOT an ID '55' on TABLE2. It committed the first TABLE1 data and continued to commit the transaction. I think that I should be checking that ID 55 exists before anything.

Comment: I think I was just testing it to fail, to catch the failed transactions - and looking for ways to cause it to fail and became confused... What else is new :\ If you want to revise your answer to cover the meaning of a transaction failure - I would be happy to credit you with the answer @dakdad - as you responded first.

Comment: I am still a little confused as to how this would work with creation of records. Would you not want to ensure a record was created before moving on to the next action?

Comment: @KDawg in general, transactions are used to rollback a series of queries if one of the queries fails. As pointed out by @Jeemusu returning empty set of results or 0 affected rows does not mean that your query failed. It simply didn't do anything. Perhaps it is best you look for the `$this->db->affected_rows()` function http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html so, if you are expecting a certain number of rows to be affected, you can rollback if the affected rows are 0. I still think you need to look at the application logic carefully and workout the data flow first :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this procedure. It work somehow ^_^

```
$this->db->trans_start();
  $this->db->query("UPDATE `TABLE1` SET `NAME` = 'AAA' WHERE `ID` = '1'");
  $this->db->query("UPDATE `TABLE2` SET `NAME` = 'BBB' WHERE `ID` = '2'");
if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){// Check if transaction result successful
   $this->db->trans_rollback();
   echo "<BR>------- TRANS FAILED -------</BR>";
}else{
   $this->db->trans_complete();
   echo "<BR>------- TRANS SUCCESS -------</BR>";
}
```

Comment: Your mySQL database table must be innodb not myISAM.